# Swift - Adding data to a dictionary

Tags: swift

So I have created a function which I use for all my requests, which will retry the request if fails and also add some of my headers to all requests for security.

The problem I am having is if `data` is nil, no values are being set in data.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
func performAndRetryRequestWithURL(method: Alamofire.Method, url: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completionHandler:(AnyObject?) -> Void) {

    var data: [String: AnyObject]?
    if (parameters != nil) {
        data = parameters!
    } else {
        data = [String: AnyObject]?()
    }

    var unixTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    // I tried both ways to add timestamp
    data?["timestamp"] = unixTime
    data?.updateValue(unixTime, forKey: "timestamp")
    data?.updateValue(hash("myfakekey"), forKey: "key")

    println(data)
```

If parameters has data it seems to append, but if parameters is nil, data will be nil also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `data` not optional:

```
var data = parameters ?? [String: AnyObject]()
```

If `parameters` is not `nil`, `data` will be assigned to `parameter`'s unwrapped value. Otherwise, it will be initialized to an empty, non-optional dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
data = [String: AnyObject]?()
```

This looks at first glance like it should create an empty dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]`, but what it actually does is create an `Optional` dictionary that is initialized to `nil`. Get rid of the `?` and it should work:

```
data = [String: AnyObject]()
```

Or, alternatively, since you've already identified `data` as being a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]?`, you could simply write:

```
data = [:]
```

That would create an empty dictionary as well.